# Is it possible to save multiple Foreign key in Laravel to be able to see many Items table in a Package Items table? in Quasar 1 Laravel 2

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, laravel-8

I'm trying to achieve some like an Ecommerce website where a Product has Many Categories.

I have this form named PackageItem table (let's compare it to PRODUCT) and when I click the Item it gets the Items name from the Item table (let's also compare it to CATEGORIES)

[image]

[image]

I have this q-select that accepts multiple items.

[image]

This is my return in Vue

```
 createOptions: [],
```

my Methods for getting the Items from the backend and bind it to the q-select

```
allPackageItemsData() {
      const bearerToken = localStorage.getItem("Bearer");

      this.$axios
        .get("http://localhost:8000/api/allPackageItems", {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${bearerToken}`,
          },
        })
        .then((response) => {
          this.allPackageItems = response.data;
          this.createOptions = response.data.map(
            (packageitem) =>
              // "(Item) " +
              packageitem.name
            // + "     &     " +
            // "(Item ID) " +
            // packageitem.id
          );
        });
    },
```

As you can see I'm mapping so that I can get the Item name and bind it to the q-select (See Package Item Form above.)

However, I need to display the names in the Frontend and upon selecting the Items name in the q-select I wanted to get the ID of it and save it to the database. **In short I need to display the name as it is but upon selecting it I need to get the ID and pass it to the database**

The reason for this is that I need to get the ID of the Items so that I can display it

I'm getting a controller like this one

```
$packageitems = DB::table('packageitems')
->select(
    'items.name',
    'packageitems.price',
)
->join('items', 'items.id', '=', 'packageitems.item_id')
->where('items.activeInactive', '=', 'Active')
->get();
```

I wanted to save a Package Item that has Many Items as many as I want and upon getting the Item names I wanted to create a price for it. Let's say it as a promo in a grocery you have 5 different chips and save the price for 2 dollar as a promo more like a LAZADA PACKAGE or SHOPEE PACKAGE.

I'm trying to achieve like this one.

This is my Create PackageItem Controller

```
   $

user = Auth::user();
        $item = Item::arrayPackageItemSelect();

        $fields = $request->validate([
            'user_id' => 'required',
            'item_id' => 'required',
            'price' => 'required|numeric'
        ]);

        
         $package = PackageItem::create([
            'user_id' => $user->id,
            'item_id' =>  implode(',' , $fields['item_id']), // If i put implode it gives 
                  //error
            'price'=> $fields['price']
        ]);

        return response()->json($package, 201);
```

I tried using implode as I seen it one of the tutorials however it is using one table only that in my case I'm doing this with a join from another table.

my package Item model.

[image]

my Item model.

[image]

so I created a function arrayPackageItemSelect that gets the Id of the Items but display it to the frontend by the name. I got this from this article https://www.artofcse.com/learning/product-view-insert-update-delete

However, I'm having a hard time figuring out this logic both the backend and frontend. I tried searching an I can't find anything I'm looking for. I wanted to make a CRUD out of this.

Answer (score 0):

first create the package with the price and user_id

then

check the request if the request->item is an array

if true  `$items = collect($request->items);` collect the request->item array

then

```
$items->each(function ($item) use ($package ) {
  $package ->items()->create($item);
});
```

this 3 lines of code will do the logic in inserting the package items referenced to the package id

on the package model

```
protected $fillable = [user_id,price];
```

public function items() {hasMany(item::class)}

item model

```
public function package(){belognsTo(packageItem::class)}
```

Comment: I don't get this, in which controller will I put this? I didn't get any of this.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).